How to create matching wavy borders for top and bottom of a container using css clip-path?
I am trying to create a container with wavy, imperfect borders on both the top and bottom. My goal is for the top border to exactly match the pattern of the bottom border.
I've attempted to achieve this using clip-path, but I'm having trouble getting the top border to match the exact ame pattern. Here’s the sample code I've tried so far:
code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wavy Border Box</title>
    <style>
        #wavy-box {
            background-color: #F50001;
            height: 400px; 
            width: 100%;
            clip-path: url(#wavy-border);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            border: none;
            color: #DC7633;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="wavy-border" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <path d="
              M0,0
              C0.05,0 0.2,0.03 0.25,0.02
              C0.3,0.015 0.35,0.02 0.35,0.025
              C0.355,0.0225 0.45,0.03 0.5,0.035
              C0.53,0.035 0.58,0.02 0.6,0.02
              C0.63,0.015 0.74,0.0275 0.75,0.03
              C0.78,0.0325 0.925,0.0125 0.95,0.015
              C0.97,0.0125 1,0.025 1,0.025
              L1,0.975
              C0.97,0.9875 0.925,0.9875 0.9,0.985
              C0.875,0.9825 0.78,0.9675 0.75,0.97
              C0.725,0.9725 0.63,0.985 0.6,0.98
              C0.58,0.98 0.53,0.965 0.5,0.965
              C0.45,0.97 0.355,0.9775 0.35,0.975
              C0.35,0.98 0.3,0.96 0.25,0.96
              C0.2,0.96 0.05,1 0,1
              Z"/>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <div id="wavy-box">
        Your content here
    </div>
</body>
</html>

As you can see in the image, the top border is inverted, But I need the same pattern as the bottom border.


Got it. My idea was to replicate the top line to the bottom, only with a +1 offset for the y's. This proved wrong as it was being trimmed after 1 so I replicated top line with an offset +0.95 for the y's.
The y's are the second numbers in each number pair x, y.
As the path though is going clockwise, I had to make some detour through the middle (Like a figure 8) so I could reach point (0,0.95) from counterclockwise direction.


body {
  background: #222;
}

#wavy-box {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  clip-path: url(#wavy-border);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  color: #DC7633;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
<body>
  <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="wavy-border" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <path d="
                M0,0
                C0.05,0 0.2,0.03 0.25,0.02
                C0.3,0.015 0.35,0.02 0.35,0.025
                C0.355,0.0225 0.45,0.03 0.5,0.035
                C0.53,0.035 0.58,0.02 0.6,0.02
                C0.63,0.015 0.74,0.0275 0.75,0.03
                C0.78,0.0325 0.925,0.0125 0.95,0.015
                C0.97,0.0125 1,0.025 1,0.025
                L1,0.5
                L0,0.5
                L0,0.95
                C0.05,0.95 0.2,0.98 0.25,0.97
                C0.3,0.965 0.35,0.97 0.35,0.975
                C0.355,0.9725 0.45,0.98 0.5,0.985
                C0.53,0.985 0.58,0.97 0.6,0.97
                C0.63,0.965 0.74,0.9775 0.75,0.98
                C0.78,0.9825 0.925,0.9625 0.95,0.965
                C0.97,0.9625 1,0.975 1,0.975
                L1,0.5
                L0,0.5
                Z" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
  <div id="wavy-box">
    Your content here
  </div>



